# Creditor badge awarded incorrectly?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, badges

Most questions about the creditor badge seem to be about *not getting* it. I got it, but only because *somebody else* added a link to an example to my answer:

[image]

This feels like a bug to me. Even though it is my answer, it was not me who added the link.

Maybe it's not possible for the system to consider edits, but I wanted to point it out.

Comment: Congratulations! Welcome to life. It's not always fair.

Comment: To be fair, it's doing exactly what it says: *First citation of a topic or example you haven't edited, in an answer you posted*. You posted the answer, the topic/example (hard to see which) was one you haven't edited, so...

Comment: This happened for all the badges to be fair :P *somebody else* always does the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that was a bug. It's been fixed now, so going forward we'll only consider links added by the answer's author either when the answer was first posted or in a subsequent revision.